# Optmising Active Record in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a very complicated funciton in one of my CI models so I try to optimise it and make it more robust.I'm not sure where exactly the problem is so I'll paste both the original(working) variant and what I have done to make it better. I think in the most part it should work but obv. I've made a mistake somewhere along the way.

Here is the original function:

```
public function get($data)
    {
        if (isset($data))
        {
            if (isset($data['sort']))
            {
                $sort = json_decode($data['sort'], true);
                $this->db->order_by($sort[0]['property'], $sort[0]['direction']);
            }

            if (isset($data['query']) && $data['query'] != '')
            {
                $fields = json_decode($data['fields'], true);
                $where = $fields[0] . " LIKE '%" . $data['query'] . "%'";
                unset($fields[0]);
                foreach ($fields as $field)
                {
                    $where .= ' OR ' . $field . ' LIKE ' . "'%" . $data['query'] . "%'";
                }
                $this->db->select('id, email, firstname, lastname, usertype, ts_created, ts_last_login, position');
                $this->db->from('users');
                $this->db->where($where);
                $this->db->limit($data['limit'], $data['start']);
                $query = $this->db->get();
                $result = $query->result_array();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->select('id, email, firstname, lastname, usertype, ts_created, ts_last_login, position');
                $this->db->from('users');
                $this->db->limit($data['limit'], $data['start']);
                $query = $this->db->get();
                $result = $query->result_array();
            }

            if ($result != null)
            {
                return $result;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $query = $this->db->select('id, email, firstname, lastname, usertype, ts_created, ts_last_login, position');
            $query = $this->db->get('users');
            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

And here is what I've done:

```
public function get($data)
    {

        if (isset($data))
        {
            if (isset($data['sort']))
            {
                $sort = json_decode($data['sort'], true);
                $orderCoulmn = $sort[0]['property'];
                $orderDir = $sort[0]['direction'];
            }

        $limit = $data['limit'];

        $start = $data['start'];

        }

        $this->db->select('id, email, firstname, lastname, usertype, ts_created, ts_last_login, position');

    /*  if (!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }*/
        if (isset($data['query']) && $data['query'] != '' )
        {
            $fields = json_decode($data['fields'], true);
            //$this->db->like($fields[0], $data['query']);
            //unset($fields[0]);

            foreach ($fields as $filed)
            {
                $this->db->or_like($field, $data['query']);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($limit) && !empty($start))
        {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        }

        if (!empty($orderColumn) && !empty($orderDir))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($orderColumn, $orderDir);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $result = $query->result_array();

        return $result;
    }
```

Any ideas where could be the problem in my code (the second one)?
Thanks
Leron

Comment: If you talk us through the code and or tell us what you want to achive it might be easier to help you.

Comment: Well, I don't know what exactly to say in addition. It's a working function part from a working program.A part from my teaching is to optimise the code. In other words to rewrite it in a better form. You can see what I mean by looking at the original file and what I've done sine now. $data is variable which has values posted from a search menu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't directly see what's wrong with your example, but this is how I would simplify things:

```
public function get($data)
{
    $this->db->select('id, email, firstname, lastname, usertype, ts_created, ts_last_login, position'); // same for every situation

    if (is_array($data)) // a little stricter than testing if it's set, could be a string.
    {
        $this->db->limit($data['limit'], $data['start']); // do anyhow if $data is an array

        if ($data['sort']) // if this evaluates to true, execute
        {
            $sort = json_decode($data['sort'], true);
            $this->db->order_by($sort[0]['property'], $sort[0]['direction']);
        }

        if ($data['query'])
        {
            $fields = json_decode($data['fields'], true);
            $where = "";
            $seperator = "";
            foreach($fields as $field)
            {
                $where .= "{$seperator}$field LIKE '%{$data['query']}%'";
                $seperator = ' OR '; // using this "seperator" approach, allows you to easily concat strings.
            }
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
    }

    // finally, get a result, with possible other db actions, depending on $data
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Remember: KISS and DRY are your friends ;)